# No apt package for kiwix-tools for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, apt

I am to run kiwix-serve a computer running Ubuntu 18.04. First I added the Kiwix PPA via:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kiwixteam/release
```

If I run `apt search kiwix` I get the following:

```
kiwix/bionic,now 2.0.5~bionic amd64 [installed]
  offline Wikipedia reader

libkiwix-dev/bionic 9.4.1~bionic amd64
  library of common code for Kiwix (development)

libkiwix0/bionic 0.2.0-1 amd64
  library of common code for Kiwix

libkiwix9/bionic,now 9.4.1~bionic amd64 [installed,automatic]
  library of common code for Kiwix
```

On another machine with 20.04 kiwix-tools appears in the list, installs, and runs with no issues.

**Update 1:**
Since the PPA seems not to have a package for 18.04 Bionic, does anyone have any suggestions on how to install kiwix-serve on 18.04 alongside the kiwix package without messing anything up?

Should also mention I tried the snap for kiwix-tools (https://snapcraft.io/install/kiwix-tools/ubuntu) and it installs but will not open any recently created Zim files. I imagine this is because it was last updated 2 years ago as of the writing of this post.

Comment: What is the actual problem? There [are packages for 18.04 LTS](https://launchpad.net/~kiwixteam/+archive/ubuntu/release/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=bionic) in the mentioned  repo. But kiwix-tools is [not available for bionic](https://launchpad.net/~kiwixteam/+archive/ubuntu/release/+packages?field.name_filter=kiwix-tools&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=). You have to ask PPA owner about its packaging.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just e-mailed a request for `kiwix-tools` [packaging](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekiwixteam/+archive/ubuntu/release?field.series_filter=bionic) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. As the result the issue was opened at https://github.com/kiwix/kiwix-tools/issues/531 .

As a workaround we can adapt [ArchLinux PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=kiwix-tools-bin) for the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kiwixteam/release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kiwix

# get kiwix-tools
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/kiwix/release/kiwix-tools/kiwix-tools_linux-x86_64-3.1.2-5.tar.gz
tar -xf kiwix-tools_linux-x86_64-3.1.2-5.tar.gz
cd kiwix-tools_linux-x86_64-3.1.2-5
sudo cp kiwix-* /usr/local/bin/
```

and then use any of `kiwix-manage`, `kiwix-read`, `kiwix-search` or `kiwix-serve` utilities as usual.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert!!! I can confirm it works on 18.04. I will be following the issue you opened. I have to wonder why the package is not included when it works just fine by using the ArchLinux PKGBUILD as you demonstrated.